# Is it possible to interactively control/manipulate objects in Blender Internal/Cycles to have more realistic physics simulations?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, physics, 3d-manipulator

I am working on a project which involves some physical interaction between different objects in a scene; Most of the physical interactions could come from manipulating objects in the scene while the physics is working. For instance, I want to make a scene in which there is a articulated hand that moves some objects as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiXAAkcPth8). I haven't been able to find anything regarding controlling objects in an interactive manner in Blender Internal and Cycles with the physics being on indefinitely. By indefinitely, I mean I do not want to set a limit for the number of frames the physics simulation should run.

So I wonder is it possible to have interactive scenes to manipulate objects using the physics in Blender Internal or Cycles?

I emphasized on Blender Internal or Cycles because the quality of physics simulations is pretty important for this project. In addition, I don't mind the physics simulation time. However, although having interactive scenes is possible in Blender Game Engine but I've heard that the physics in Blender Game Engine is only meant to be used for real-time simulations and is not realistic. I wonder if that is true? If that is the case, is there any workaround to either make Blender Game Engine use the physics that are being used in Cycles/Internal?

P.S. I've heard that Blender 2.8 can potentially resolve this issue as it is possible to have interactive scenes with high-quality physics in it. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: There will be some interactive mode in coming Blender 2.8 but probably not 2.80 rather 2.8x. But what it will be? Nobody knows. It's a long one but explains something: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hy-evMc3Z_I

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing physics, rendering and interaction, which are three different worlds in a 3d package like blender. If you want interaction then you need to use any game engine like unreal, optimized to calculate simulations (based on assumptions) as well as additional interactions in real-time.

However, with that benefit of having a real-time simulation, you *obviously* forfeit simulation quality and especially image quality. Notice that even in a game engine, the simulation of physics only means object interaction and is another thing as how all the meshes are calculated to a final image.

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned I don't mind the simulation time and it is very important to me to have realistic renderings, at some point at least. I can do the physics simulations in other environments and use Blender for rendering only but most other physics engines have some assumptions that leads to unrealistic physics simulations as they are designed for purposes like game playing etc.

Comment: Maybe in a decade @Amir. Not sure what your definition of high quality is but in case you want real-time interaction, you can't wait for any sim to calculate so time matters and there is no way around *low quality*. Next thing is that real-time path tracing is impossible to achieve with available hardware. Half year ago, there was [this real-time path tracing demo by nvidia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3ue35ago3Y) build in unreal. However, the movie is rendered with an experimental, absolute priceless gpu card rig, without any complex interactions and combined with their denoiser AI.

Comment: The reason that I'm looking to have interaction does not necessarily mean I want to make a game and play it in real time. I basically just want to move the objects in the scene and have them collide with one another. However, having to fix the maximum number of frames for physics simulations is one of the biggest hurtles for me.

Comment: For the example you've provided in the question, interacting with toys on the table, there is no way around any game engine no matter if you call it game, installation or whatever at the end. Even colliding with each other (in high quality) is not possible in real-time with current hardware and software that isn't optimized for that one task @Amir